# how to set VSCodium as git difftool

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-config, git-difftool

I tried to set VS-codium (VSCode[Visual-Studio Code] without telemetry data) as  git difftool in Fedora linux  when I used `git difftool` command I had an error for not existin `--wait` command. 
I used these command in  my terminal:

> `git config --global diff.tool codium`
>
> `git config --global difftool.codium.cmd "codium --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE"` .

i also tried this solution .

```
# Add the following to your .gitconfig file.
[diff]
    tool = codium
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "codium"]
    cmd = codium "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

for above solution when I'm using  `git difftool` command two windows will be opened but they are  empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution for my problem:

> in **.gitconfig** file(**`git config --global -e`** ) i added **"--diff"** **"--wait"** and it work
>
> ```
>  [diff]
>       tool = codium
>    [difftool]
>       prompt = false
>    [difftool "codium"]
>       cmd = codium "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "--diff" "--wait"
> ```